# Problem after ejecting application using expo

Tags: react-native, expo

After having launched the command `npm run eject`, I follow those steps:

1. Bare: I'd like a bare React Native project.
2. I set the name of the app and the xcode project

The command return this message `Ejected successfully!`
After that, into the `ios` generated folder I run the command `pod install` and the result is `Pod installation complete!`

After performing this procedure I try to run the application using a `ios` simulator, but I have this error:

> The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project.

Note that before executing the `npm run eject` command the app worked correctly.

This is the `package.json` before the `eject`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "expo-font": "^6.0.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-apollo": "^3.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^8.0.1",
    "react-native-circle-checkbox": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-signature-pad": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.12.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

After `eject` the `package.json` has become:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.1.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.5.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "expo-font": "^6.0.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-apollo": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-camera-kit": "^8.0.1",
    "react-native-circle-checkbox": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-signature-pad": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.12.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run your project?

Comment: @Andrew I lounch the project using the following command: `npm run ios`

Comment: Have you tried building the app through Xcode?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you have an AppLoading from "expo" package in the App.js that doesn't have support without que ExpoSDK. You have to erase that and put the fonts in the componentDidMount()